# Allocate struct vector memory dynamically

Tags: c, vector, struct, malloc

I don't know what is the correct way to allocate memory dynamically:
I have a ***.csv*** file which has like 50 lines and I need to allocate enough space in memory to save each line of the file in one space of the struct vector.

Also, I know that the return of ***malloc*** is the first position of the allocated memory space.

**Example:**

```
typedef struct{
   int a;
   float b;
   char name[10]; //This will be set dynamically too, later...
}my_struct;

int main(){
   int *p_array;
   size_t vector_size = 2;  //Same as doing:  my_struct struc[2]   ?

   p_array = (int *) malloc(vector_size * (int));
   my_struct struc[p_array];

   return 0;
}
```

Is it right? If not which is the right way of doing it. I got no errors, but I don't know why it doesn't seems right.

Comment: What is this `my_strict struc[p]` for? and whre is `p` defined? Your code does not compile, you must post a compilable example. The first answer I can give is that it's wrong because it doesn't compile.

Comment: @iharob I edited my question. Take a look at this and let me know if it still confused. I need to create a vector of my struct, but it's size has to be set dynamically according to the number of lines in my *.csv* file.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro It's still not clear what `p` is (it's never defined in your program).. Also, your `//Same as doing:  my_struct struc[2]` comment isn't very clear.. What do you mean by it?

Comment: "*I got no errors*" I doubt this.

Comment: Do each line in the file have a constant number of characters?

Comment: @CoolGuy No, it vary. It's content is like: *name,AccNumber,cash...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely wrong, starting here

1. This is wrong

   ```
   p_array = (int *) malloc(vector_size * (int));
   /*                                       ^ what is this? */
   ```

   if you want an array of integers of `vector_size` size you need

   ```
    p_array = malloc(vector_size * sizeof(int));
    /*                                ^ the sizeof operator */
   ```
2. This doesn't make sense at all

   ```
   my_struct struc[p_array];
   ```

   maybe you mean?

   ```
   my_struct struc[vector_size];
   ```

   above you are passing a pointer where an integer should go, if this compiles then what is happening is that the address stored in the pointer is evaluated as an integer and hence your `struc` array has a size very different than what you think

   If you use the corrected version of this, the `malloc()` makes absolutely no sense, so you don't really need it.

If you want to allocate the `struc` array dynamically then

```
my_struct *array;

array = malloc(elementCount * sizeof(my_struct)):
if (array == NULL)
    pleaseDoNot_Use_array_AndProbably_AbortHere();
/* you can use it here, and when you finish */
free(array);
```

If you enable compiler warnings there will be a few warnings that will let you know some of the things I mentioned above.

Also, in c [There is no need to cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495)

Comment: ***my_struct struc[vector_size];*** Yes sir. Sorry about that.

Comment: *elementcount* is the number of lines I have, right ?

Comment: It's the number of elements in the struct array.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro , Yes. You can also replace that with 50 if you want(since the file contains 50 lines).

Comment: @CoolGuy but in that case the why to `malloc()` just `my_struct array[50]` will do.

Comment: @iharob Just dont get 1 thing yet. What is `array` exactly? Is it the address  of the allocated space? sorry about dumb questions

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro yes it is, and you can access the allocated space using array index notation because that is translated to pointer arithmetic, so `array[0]` is the first element, `array[1]` the second, and so on.

Comment: @iharob I reformulated my code but still getting error. Do I write the new code in the question ?